# A New Formula for Variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

I came across the following information on statistics and probability:

[image]

I am trying to understand the rationale behind the second line - i.e. the "variance" formula. Is there some reference which shows why the variance of a random variable can be written in the following way?

For example, I have often seen the variance of a random variable (e.g. var(y)) written as "the expectation of the random variable squared minus the square of the expectation of the rando variable".

But I have never seen the variance of a random variable written in the above way.

**Can someone please provide some intuition as to how and why the variance of "y" can be written in the following way?**

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use images of text; write the text itself.

Comment: This is the Law of total variance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the law of total variance.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance